# Oracle: keep a table up to date to another

Tags: database, oracle

We use Oracle database and now I face a problem.

We need to copy a subset of columns from table A to a new table B:

```
Table A
Name|Birth Date|Location|Office

Table B
Name|Location
```

And table A will change quite often (several times in a month). And it's managed by another team.

What is the best way to keep synchronized the table B from table A ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: May we ask what the point even is of having a table B, if its records would always be completely contained within table A?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of a new table - think of a **view** or a **materialized view**.

View won't even occupy any space, it is just a stored query:

```
create or replace view v_b as
  select name, location
  from some_user.table_a;
```

It would *always* be "synchronized", you'd instantly see all committed data that belongs to `some_user`.

A materialized view occupies space, acts as if it was another table - you can even create indexes on it. Set it to refresh in a scheduled manner (for example, every night) or on demand or whenever `some_user` commits changes made in their `table_a`.

If I were you, I wouldn't create another table; (materialized) view seems to be a more appropriate solution.

Comment: And unless there is a lot of expensive aggregation going on (doesn't sound like there is) I'd recommend the OP go with the view rather than the MV.

Comment: Yes, thank you, @EdStevens. I kind of thought that it is obvious.

Comment: Views and Materialized Views function across database links. So it doesn't matter that much if the `table B` is in another database, although that might lend weight to the use of an MV.

Comment: @Littlefoot - obvious to you and me, perhaps not so much to the OP.  :-)

Comment: Thank you, @APC; rephrased.